# How to use attribute grammar to parse a string into classes

Tags: boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I like the idea of using attribute grammar to directly parse an input string and fill in a `struct` after adapting it to a random access sequence using `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT` and was wondering if it's possible to adapt a class with private members and setter/getter functions to behave the same way?

Comment: See [BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_ADT](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/adapted.html) and friends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by sehe, I was looking for BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_ADT.